# NHiberate mapping question

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 entities- `Classroom` and `Section`, that I need help with NHibernate mapping. A `Classroom` has a collection of `Sections`. And the `Section` has a reference back to its owner `Classroom`.

**On the code side:**

```
public class Classroom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }         
    public ISet<Section> Sections { get; set; } 
}

public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Classroom Classroom { get; set; } 
}
```

**On the database side:**

```
CREATE TABLE Classroom (
   ClassroomID int
)

CREATE TABLE ClassroomSection (
   ClassroomID int, 
   SectionID int,
   IsActive bit
)

CREATE TABLE Section (
   SectionID
)
```

As seen above, even though this is a *one-to-many* mapping, there is a 3rd mapping table `ClassroomSection`. Moveover this mapping table has some of its own fields, like `IsActive`. I don't want to create an entity for ClassroomSection in my code because it doesn't have any domain logic. But I do want to have access to the fields in this table. Any help with bidirectional mapping is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ClassroomSection is a value object rather than an entity, is that correct?

Comment: I don't think ClassroomSection is anything. Its just a mapping table between Classroom and Section.

Answer (score 0):

Post some sample code of how you'd like to be able to access IsActive.

Ayende's latest post might give some hints to what you're trying to accomplish: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx

Comment: You ask an excellent question. I don't know why I didn't think about this before. How should I access IsActive? I could have it live in the Section entity. Then I could do a <join> to ClassroomSection in the Section mapping. But Section itself has an IsActive field. Looks like I may have to create a ClassroomSection entity after all. I don't think there is getting around it.